# How to disable single click to open files and folders? (GUI appears disabled)

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-registry

Files and directories get open when I single click them. Watching the folder configuration I found out I have the double click option checked and the single click option is disabled so I can't change this option from the GUI.

[image]

I've been searching on google about this optiond and in older windows versions it was stored in tis registry:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
>   ClassicShell

Still I can't find it in windows 10. Which registry do I need to edit? Is there an other way to changing this configuration or enable de GUI?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your Folder Options dialog window?   Aside form that, Explorer settings are User-centric, so it's configuration is held in the HKCU branch of the registry.  Specifically it's `ShellState` binary setting in the `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer` key.  What's yours currently set to (it'll be a long number)?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 The current value for ShellState under current user configuration is 24 00 00 00 96 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 13 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 62 00 00 00. Also, screenshot added to the question (it's in spanish...)

Comment: Try the .bat files in [this article](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/10117-single-click-double-click-open-item.html).

Comment: @harrymc Those were prepared for windows 7 and all they do is create the `ClassicShell` which looks deprecated in windows 10 and update de `ShellState` which (I don't actually know) might be diferent in Win10.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `ShellState` in `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer` combined with `ClassicShell=0` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer` worked for me.

- The "ClassicShell" value changes a Policy that makes this strange thing: correct boxes checked, but incorrect behavior of explorer.exe. This correspond to the GPO setting "Turn on Classic Shell" under "User Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows Explorer". Normally the values in the properties windows are grayed out if set.
- The "ShellState" value contains the configuration of explorer.exe.

It is not really clear what the values mean, [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759788(v=vs.85).aspx) tells you to set `Type: BOOL` but the value in the registry doesn't look like that.

I changed the values on a pc so that it worked (check the option "single click" save+close and then open properties again and check the "double click" option). Then I copied the values from the registry to get my desired configuration to use it on other machines.

You have to "restart" explorer.exe (using taskmanager) or restart you pc.

Answers found here:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/cc220a3d-1a68-441e-9dc0-a5d4714bccdd/quotsingleclick-to-openquot-in-windows-explorer-registry?forum=w7itproui

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759788(v=vs.85).aspx

https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/23805821/'Turn-on-Classic-shell'-causes-single-click-in-Explorer-exe.html

Buena suerte!

Comment: MSDN is correct, they are not BOOLs, they are bitfield BOOLs (1 bit per item)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, press WINKEY + R and paste the command bellow:
"**%ProgramFiles%\internet explorer\iexplore.exe**"

Go to Options and set your underline link settings and set it to "Never".
[image]

See if it works.